# What is the average block time or confirmation time of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, block-time

Solana is fast, but exactly how fast? What is the average block time of each transaction? Has the speed increased or decreased since Solana's creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the 1-minute or 1-hour average block time on the [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/).

What you're looking for is `Slot time (1min average)` and `Slot time (1hr average)`

Comment: i thought it was sub second block times?

Comment: `652ms` is sub second. Where are you looking for block times ?